# Como fazer um "for" que grava seus valores num array?

Tags: javascript

Tenho este for que vai pegar todos os dados  `"this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].descr;"` e `"this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].valor;"` queria pegar esse valores e fazer um array com eles, depois pegar esses valores armazenados no array em outra página com javascript.

Pensei em algo assim:

```
var myarry = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++) {
  if (i == (this.qtd - 1)) {
    this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].descr;
    this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].valor;
  } else {
    //  this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].descr;
    //  this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].valor;

    myarray[0] = this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].descr;
    myarray[1] = this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].descr;
    myarray[2] = this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].descr;
    myarray[3] = this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].descr;
    myarray[4] = this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].descr;

    alert(myarray[0]);
  }
```

Comment: Utilize: `myarray.push(seuvalor);` (Observe também que sua declaração está diferente do que você usa). `var myarry = new Array();`e você está chamando por `myarray`.

Comment: Você quer que cada par descr/valor seja uma posição na array? Seria legal postar um exemplo mais completo, que possa ser executado. Ver [Como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](/help/mcve).

Comment: @bfavaretto Isso mesmo que cada par seja uma posição do Array !

Comment: btw, você pode usar `var myarray = []` ao invés do `new Array()`.  É mais simples e eficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que percebo do teu problema precisas de usar o [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) dessa maneira podes usar uma array inicial e refazer o seu conteúdo.

Vejo também no teu código que queres dar um tratamento diferente ao ultimo elemento, podes usar o `.pop()` que retorna o ultimo elemento de uma array **e remove-o** ao mesmo tempo.

Sugestão:

```
var ultimo = data.usuarios.pop();
this.retorno += ultimo.descr + ultimo.valor;
var myArray = data.usuarios.map(function(obj){
    return this.retorno += data.usuarios[i].descr;
});
```

Se não perceberes a resposta ou precisares de um exemplo junta mais código e dados de exemplo na pergunta para eu te poder ajudar mais.

Comment: tem como fazer com que cada par seja uma posição do Array ?

Comment: @nardo_bruxo sim, podes fazer um objeto para cada posição. Algo como `return {descr: ..., val: ... };` mas aí vais parar +/- ao que já tinhas inicialmente.